# Alguém me consegue explicar o porquê deste erro?

Tags: c#

Código:

```
   int jogo = 0;

   public void ganhou()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("O jogador " + jogador_atual + " ganhou!");
      reniciar();
      jogo++;
      lb_numero_jogo.Text = Convert.ToInt32(jogo);
   }
```

> Erro: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'.

[image: iPrint do erro]

Comment: Primeiramente, que tipo de variável é "JOGO" int? Pois o que o erro diz é "Não é possível fazer uma conversão implícita de "int" para "string"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O C# é **fortemente tipado**, ou seja, ao atribuir um valor a uma `string`, por exemplo, o valor também deve ser uma `string`.

Tente dessa forma:

```
MessageBox.Show("O jogador " + jogador_atual + " ganhou!");
reniciar();
jogo++;
lb_numero_jogo.Text = jogo.ToString();
```

Comment: Consegues explicar melhor o porquê de assim dar e com int não. O meu programa tinha 3 string se não me engano mas nesse caso não envolvia nenhuma string. Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda

Comment: Você está atribuindo um valor à propriedade "lb_numero.jogo.Text", que é uma String. Logo, o que você atribuir à ela também deve ser uma String. Por padrão, toda variável ou objeto no C# tem um método ".ToString()", apenas fiz uso dela.